# Dijkstra without Combinatorica

Tags: graphs-and-networks, combinatorica

There is some overlap between Combinatorica and the Graph related framework but there are also various elements missing. As far as I can see there is no 'Dijkstra' method or algorithm in Mathematica or is there a way (combination of other Graph methods) to do it? That is, without accessing Combinatorica by converting Graph to an EdgeList and so on.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[`FindShortestPath`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FindShortestPath.html) supports two methods "BellmanFord" and "Dijkstra" and it works on normal non-combinatorica Graphs.

Comment: Wonderful, so well hidden. Thanks.

Comment: @FrancoisVanderseypen It's not hidden at all. Just type `Dijkstra` in the search bar, and you get a long list  with hits. `FindShortestPath` is the fourth one in my list.

Comment: Searching for Dinitz, Prim's or Kruskal doesn't reveal much. My question was more general but I refrained from asking too much.